# Fullcalendar events not visible on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using the Fullcalendar library for a project, I followed the documentation but I noticed that on mobile I don't get to see the calendar itself, just the headings (prev, next).

I tried several cases. For instance, when I click on *week* or *day* the view loads and it works, it seems like it doesn't load properly on page load.

Here is my index, where I call the required libraries:

**Head of index.html**

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css' />
```

**Bottom of the index page**

```
<!-- scripts -->
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/material.min.js"></script>

<script src='node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js'></script>

<script src="js/jquery.sticky-kit.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: These code snippets are just your included libraries. Post your code that actually uses FullCalendar

Comment: Oh that's the thing, I didn't use it yet. I'm just displaying the empty calendar